# seaborn lineplot does not align with boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, line-plot

So I wanted to plot a dataframe with seaborn with per-minute heart rate boxplot and per minute (accumulated) distance line I ran.

When I plot that, the box plot seem to be in right position.  But as you can see from the dataframe, the distance starts to accumulate at the minute '4'.  However, the line only starts at the minute of '8'.  The lineplot is somehow shifted to the right and I cannot figure out why.
This is what I get:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="Minute", y="heart_rate", data=df10)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="Minute", y="heart_rate", data=df10, color=".25")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x="Minute", y="distance", ax=ax2, data=df10)
```

[image]

This is the dataframe I have:

```
{'distance': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 1.32,
  3: 12.19,
  4: 14.08,
  5: 14.08,
  6: 14.99,
  7: 16.95,
  8: 20.6,
  9: 26.36,
  10: 36.47,
  11: 37.95,
  12: 39.15,
  13: 40.23,
  14: 43.0,
  15: 54.29,
  16: 58.1,
  17: 64.17,
  18: 65.67,
  19: 67.74,
  20: 73.35,
  21: 75.83,
  22: 81.6,
  23: 86.46,
  24: 92.13,
  25: 93.68,
  26: 101.15,
  27: 110.88,
  28: 125.8,
  29: 139.09,
  30: 159.68,
  31: 162.47,
  32: 183.69,
  33: 186.99,
  34: 206.46,
  35: 218.11,
  36: 238.84,
  37: 252.29,
  38: 253.44,
  39: 272.69,
  40: 291.06,
  41: 310.51,
  42: 330.49,
  43: 352.44,
  44: 357.53,
  45: 378.19,
  46: 380.49,
  47: 402.49,
  48: 424.59,
  49: 441.24,
  50: 459.23,
  51: 461.68,
  52: 470.52,
  53: 472.84,
  54: 484.69,
  55: 502.42,
  56: 522.84,
  57: 525.45,
  58: 544.03,
  59: 547.13,
  60: 564.08,
  61: 579.5,
  62: 595.68,
  63: 617.98,
  64: 634.32,
  65: 646.85,
  66: 650.65,
  67: 662.39,
  68: 676.46,
  69: 688.69,
  70: 690.65,
  71: 701.23,
  72: 720.75,
  73: 736.94,
  74: 758.71,
  75: 774.83,
  76: 776.95,
  77: 791.73,
  78: 793.25,
  79: 813.79,
  80: 826.32,
  81: 847.63,
  82: 869.13,
  83: 869.9,
  84: 872.29,
  85: 873.7,
  86: 877.65,
  87: 880.11,
  88: 891.86,
  89: 900.85,
  90: 909.07,
  91: 912.57,
  92: 926.31,
  93: 931.2,
  94: 951.15,
  95: 972.55,
  96: 993.24,
  97: 996.78,
  98: 1017.75,
  99: 1024.88,
  100: 1045.62,
  101: 1048.41,
  102: 1070.19,
  103: 1079.69,
  104: 1079.95,
  105: 1080.64,
  106: 1081.25,
  107: 1081.71,
  108: 1081.71,
  109: 1081.71,
  110: 1085.0,
  111: 1088.89,
  112: 1091.65,
  113: 1097.36,
  114: 1107.23,
  115: 1112.29,
  116: 1124.21,
  117: 1131.54,
  118: 1143.32,
  119: 1154.14,
  120: 1176.21,
  121: 1179.65,
  122: 1193.0,
  123: 1215.3,
  124: 1221.3,
  125: 1227.19,
  126: 1233.66,
  127: 1256.04,
  128: 1258.82,
  129: 1278.99,
  130: 1294.85,
  131: 1297.02,
  132: 1305.39,
  133: 1324.05,
  134: 1337.78,
  135: 1358.49,
  136: 1363.4,
  137: 1381.39,
  138: 1389.2,
  139: 1393.23,
  140: 1396.54,
  141: 1397.89,
  142: 1414.57,
  143: 1428.97,
  144: 1449.31,
  145: 1468.44,
  146: 1480.76,
  147: 1498.9,
  148: 1509.63,
  149: 1527.32,
  150: 1538.07,
  151: 1542.23,
  152: 1556.08,
  153: 1572.01,
  154: 1584.36,
  155: 1586.84,
  156: 1598.14,
  157: 1600.05,
  158: 1604.06,
  159: 1611.76,
  160: 1614.68,
  161: 1621.1,
  162: 1624.14,
  163: 1631.55,
  164: 1636.01,
  165: 1640.78,
  166: 1660.03,
  167: 1666.56,
  168: 1667.15,
  169: 1673.02,
  170: 1677.41,
  171: 1683.5,
  172: 1700.03,
  173: 1718.21,
  174: 1728.97,
  175: 1741.63,
  176: 1751.83,
  177: 1772.14,
  178: 1787.09,
  179: 1803.45,
  180: 1823.71,
  181: 1828.67,
  182: 1837.57,
  183: 1842.22,
  184: 1847.98,
  185: 1866.49,
  186: 1885.0,
  187: 1904.97,
  188: 1922.26,
  189: 1937.47,
  190: 1940.28,
  191: 1956.87,
  192: 1962.14,
  193: 1965.9,
  194: 1976.61,
  195: 1997.43,
  196: 2019.13,
  197: 2042.57,
  198: 2045.53,
  199: 2060.85,
  200: 2076.46,
  201: 2096.72,
  202: 2098.65,
  203: 2115.07,
  204: 2135.01,
  205: 2149.51,
  206: 2165.82,
  207: 2181.52,
  208: 2187.37,
  209: 2189.12,
  210: 2202.08,
  211: 2221.33,
  212: 2231.27,
  213: 2241.26,
  214: 2245.25,
  215: 2253.94,
  216: 2260.61,
  217: 2280.94,
  218: 2289.1,
  219: 2297.8,
  220: 2318.97,
  221: 2340.61,
  222: 2361.73,
  223: 2366.2,
  224: 2383.01,
  225: 2396.53,
  226: 2397.64,
  227: 2402.96,
  228: 2404.77,
  229: 2411.25,
  230: 2415.46,
  231: 2434.33,
  232: 2436.76,
  233: 2451.44,
  234: 2472.08,
  235: 2488.44,
  236: 2491.16,
  237: 2504.45,
  238: 2524.33,
  239: 2542.52,
  240: 2553.94,
  241: 2559.52,
  242: 2576.69,
  243: 2597.31,
  244: 2609.64,
  245: 2617.46},
 'heart_rate': {0: 68.0,
  1: 68.0,
  2: 71.0,
  3: 77.0,
  4: 80.0,
  5: 83.0,
  6: 83.0,
  7: 86.0,
  8: 90.0,
  9: 92.0,
  10: 94.0,
  11: 91.0,
  12: 88.0,
  13: 87.0,
  14: 84.0,
  15: 82.0,
  16: 79.0,
  17: 81.0,
  18: 83.0,
  19: 82.0,
  20: 84.0,
  21: 87.0,
  22: 92.0,
  23: 94.0,
  24: 97.0,
  25: 98.0,
  26: 101.0,
  27: 101.0,
  28: 102.0,
  29: 103.0,
  30: 104.0,
  31: 104.0,
  32: 105.0,
  33: 105.0,
  34: 106.0,
  35: 107.0,
  36: 107.0,
  37: 107.0,
  38: 107.0,
  39: 110.0,
  40: 111.0,
  41: 110.0,
  42: 111.0,
  43: 111.0,
  44: 111.0,
  45: 113.0,
  46: 113.0,
  47: 112.0,
  48: 111.0,
  49: 111.0,
  50: 112.0,
  51: 112.0,
  52: 113.0,
  53: 113.0,
  54: 112.0,
  55: 110.0,
  56: 111.0,
  57: 112.0,
  58: 114.0,
  59: 114.0,
  60: 114.0,
  61: 113.0,
  62: 112.0,
  63: 114.0,
  64: 112.0,
  65: 112.0,
  66: 112.0,
  67: 113.0,
  68: 112.0,
  69: 113.0,
  70: 113.0,
  71: 114.0,
  72: 115.0,
  73: 114.0,
  74: 114.0,
  75: 115.0,
  76: 116.0,
  77: 115.0,
  78: 115.0,
  79: 117.0,
  80: 117.0,
  81: 118.0,
  82: 119.0,
  83: 118.0,
  84: 115.0,
  85: 112.0,
  86: 109.0,
  87: 107.0,
  88: 108.0,
  89: 111.0,
  90: 114.0,
  91: 114.0,
  92: 117.0,
  93: 117.0,
  94: 119.0,
  95: 120.0,
  96: 120.0,
  97: 120.0,
  98: 119.0,
  99: 119.0,
  100: 120.0,
  101: 120.0,
  102: 119.0,
  103: 119.0,
  104: 119.0,
  105: 118.0,
  106: 116.0,
  107: 113.0,
  108: 111.0,
  109: 108.0,
  110: 107.0,
  111: 107.0,
  112: 107.0,
  113: 108.0,
  114: 111.0,
  115: 113.0,
  116: 116.0,
  117: 116.0,
  118: 119.0,
  119: 119.0,
  120: 120.0,
  121: 121.0,
  122: 122.0,
  123: 122.0,
  124: 122.0,
  125: 123.0,
  126: 123.0,
  127: 124.0,
  128: 125.0,
  129: 125.0,
  130: 127.0,
  131: 127.0,
  132: 126.0,
  133: 128.0,
  134: 128.0,
  135: 128.0,
  136: 128.0,
  137: 129.0,
  138: 129.0,
  139: 130.0,
  140: 130.0,
  141: 130.0,
  142: 129.0,
  143: 129.0,
  144: 128.0,
  145: 128.0,
  146: 128.0,
  147: 127.0,
  148: 127.0,
  149: 127.0,
  150: 128.0,
  151: 128.0,
  152: 126.0,
  153: 126.0,
  154: 126.0,
  155: 126.0,
  156: 126.0,
  157: 126.0,
  158: 126.0,
  159: 127.0,
  160: 127.0,
  161: 127.0,
  162: 128.0,
  163: 127.0,
  164: 126.0,
  165: 126.0,
  166: 127.0,
  167: 128.0,
  168: 128.0,
  169: 124.0,
  170: 121.0,
  171: 120.0,
  172: 123.0,
  173: 125.0,
  174: 128.0,
  175: 129.0,
  176: 130.0,
  177: 129.0,
  178: 130.0,
  179: 129.0,
  180: 130.0,
  181: 130.0,
  182: 128.0,
  183: 128.0,
  184: 129.0,
  185: 129.0,
  186: 131.0,
  187: 131.0,
  188: 131.0,
  189: 131.0,
  190: 131.0,
  191: 130.0,
  192: 130.0,
  193: 130.0,
  194: 132.0,
  195: 131.0,
  196: 132.0,
  197: 134.0,
  198: 134.0,
  199: 133.0,
  200: 134.0,
  201: 134.0,
  202: 134.0,
  203: 136.0,
  204: 137.0,
  205: 135.0,
  206: 136.0,
  207: 136.0,
  208: 135.0,
  209: 135.0,
  210: 135.0,
  211: 135.0,
  212: 135.0,
  213: 134.0,
  214: 134.0,
  215: 133.0,
  216: 133.0,
  217: 133.0,
  218: 133.0,
  219: 132.0,
  220: 132.0,
  221: 134.0,
  222: 133.0,
  223: 133.0,
  224: 134.0,
  225: 134.0,
  226: 134.0,
  227: 133.0,
  228: 133.0,
  229: 133.0,
  230: 133.0,
  231: 134.0,
  232: 133.0,
  233: 134.0,
  234: 132.0,
  235: 131.0,
  236: 131.0,
  237: 132.0,
  238: 132.0,
  239: 131.0,
  240: 131.0,
  241: 130.0,
  242: 129.0,
  243: 130.0,
  244: 131.0,
  245: 132.0},
 'HHMMSS': {0: datetime.time(21, 4, 3),
  1: datetime.time(21, 4, 4),
  2: datetime.time(21, 4, 7),
  3: datetime.time(21, 4, 14),
  4: datetime.time(21, 4, 15),
  5: datetime.time(21, 4, 16),
  6: datetime.time(21, 4, 17),
  7: datetime.time(21, 4, 18),
  8: datetime.time(21, 4, 20),
  9: datetime.time(21, 4, 22),
  10: datetime.time(21, 4, 29),
  11: datetime.time(21, 4, 33),
  12: datetime.time(21, 4, 35),
  13: datetime.time(21, 4, 36),
  14: datetime.time(21, 4, 38),
  15: datetime.time(21, 4, 44),
  16: datetime.time(21, 4, 46),
  17: datetime.time(21, 4, 49),
  18: datetime.time(21, 4, 50),
  19: datetime.time(21, 4, 51),
  20: datetime.time(21, 4, 53),
  21: datetime.time(21, 4, 54),
  22: datetime.time(21, 4, 56),
  23: datetime.time(21, 4, 58),
  24: datetime.time(21, 5),
  25: datetime.time(21, 5, 1),
  26: datetime.time(21, 5, 4),
  27: datetime.time(21, 5, 8),
  28: datetime.time(21, 5, 14),
  29: datetime.time(21, 5, 20),
  30: datetime.time(21, 5, 27),
  31: datetime.time(21, 5, 28),
  32: datetime.time(21, 5, 36),
  33: datetime.time(21, 5, 37),
  34: datetime.time(21, 5, 44),
  35: datetime.time(21, 5, 49),
  36: datetime.time(21, 5, 57),
  37: datetime.time(21, 6, 3),
  38: datetime.time(21, 6, 4),
  39: datetime.time(21, 6, 12),
  40: datetime.time(21, 6, 20),
  41: datetime.time(21, 6, 28),
  42: datetime.time(21, 6, 36),
  43: datetime.time(21, 6, 44),
  44: datetime.time(21, 6, 46),
  45: datetime.time(21, 6, 54),
  46: datetime.time(21, 6, 55),
  47: datetime.time(21, 7, 3),
  48: datetime.time(21, 7, 11),
  49: datetime.time(21, 7, 18),
  50: datetime.time(21, 7, 25),
  51: datetime.time(21, 7, 26),
  52: datetime.time(21, 7, 30),
  53: datetime.time(21, 7, 31),
  54: datetime.time(21, 7, 37),
  55: datetime.time(21, 7, 45),
  56: datetime.time(21, 7, 53),
  57: datetime.time(21, 7, 54),
  58: datetime.time(21, 8, 2),
  59: datetime.time(21, 8, 3),
  60: datetime.time(21, 8, 9),
  61: datetime.time(21, 8, 16),
  62: datetime.time(21, 8, 22),
  63: datetime.time(21, 8, 31),
  64: datetime.time(21, 8, 38),
  65: datetime.time(21, 8, 43),
  66: datetime.time(21, 8, 45),
  67: datetime.time(21, 8, 52),
  68: datetime.time(21, 8, 58),
  69: datetime.time(21, 9, 4),
  70: datetime.time(21, 9, 5),
  71: datetime.time(21, 9, 11),
  72: datetime.time(21, 9, 20),
  73: datetime.time(21, 9, 27),
  74: datetime.time(21, 9, 35),
  75: datetime.time(21, 9, 42),
  76: datetime.time(21, 9, 43),
  77: datetime.time(21, 9, 49),
  78: datetime.time(21, 9, 50),
  79: datetime.time(21, 9, 59),
  80: datetime.time(21, 10, 5),
  81: datetime.time(21, 10, 14),
  82: datetime.time(21, 10, 24),
  83: datetime.time(21, 10, 25),
  84: datetime.time(21, 10, 32),
  85: datetime.time(21, 10, 35),
  86: datetime.time(21, 10, 38),
  87: datetime.time(21, 10, 39),
  88: datetime.time(21, 10, 44),
  89: datetime.time(21, 10, 48),
  90: datetime.time(21, 10, 51),
  91: datetime.time(21, 10, 52),
  92: datetime.time(21, 10, 57),
  93: datetime.time(21, 10, 59),
  94: datetime.time(21, 11, 6),
  95: datetime.time(21, 11, 13),
  96: datetime.time(21, 11, 19),
  97: datetime.time(21, 11, 20),
  98: datetime.time(21, 11, 26),
  99: datetime.time(21, 11, 28),
  100: datetime.time(21, 11, 35),
  101: datetime.time(21, 11, 36),
  102: datetime.time(21, 11, 45),
  103: datetime.time(21, 11, 51),
  104: datetime.time(21, 11, 52),
  105: datetime.time(21, 11, 56),
  106: datetime.time(21, 11, 59),
  107: datetime.time(21, 12, 2),
  108: datetime.time(21, 12, 4),
  109: datetime.time(21, 12, 7),
  110: datetime.time(21, 12, 11),
  111: datetime.time(21, 12, 12),
  112: datetime.time(21, 12, 13),
  113: datetime.time(21, 12, 15),
  114: datetime.time(21, 12, 18),
  115: datetime.time(21, 12, 20),
  116: datetime.time(21, 12, 24),
  117: datetime.time(21, 12, 27),
  118: datetime.time(21, 12, 31),
  119: datetime.time(21, 12, 35),
  120: datetime.time(21, 12, 43),
  121: datetime.time(21, 12, 45),
  122: datetime.time(21, 12, 50),
  123: datetime.time(21, 12, 58),
  124: datetime.time(21, 13),
  125: datetime.time(21, 13, 3),
  126: datetime.time(21, 13, 6),
  127: datetime.time(21, 13, 15),
  128: datetime.time(21, 13, 16),
  129: datetime.time(21, 13, 24),
  130: datetime.time(21, 13, 32),
  131: datetime.time(21, 13, 33),
  132: datetime.time(21, 13, 37),
  133: datetime.time(21, 13, 46),
  134: datetime.time(21, 13, 53),
  135: datetime.time(21, 14, 2),
  136: datetime.time(21, 14, 4),
  137: datetime.time(21, 14, 13),
  138: datetime.time(21, 14, 19),
  139: datetime.time(21, 14, 22),
  140: datetime.time(21, 14, 25),
  141: datetime.time(21, 14, 26),
  142: datetime.time(21, 14, 36),
  143: datetime.time(21, 14, 44),
  144: datetime.time(21, 14, 53),
  145: datetime.time(21, 15, 1),
  146: datetime.time(21, 15, 7),
  147: datetime.time(21, 15, 14),
  148: datetime.time(21, 15, 20),
  149: datetime.time(21, 15, 28),
  150: datetime.time(21, 15, 33),
  151: datetime.time(21, 15, 35),
  152: datetime.time(21, 15, 41),
  153: datetime.time(21, 15, 48),
  154: datetime.time(21, 15, 53),
  155: datetime.time(21, 15, 54),
  156: datetime.time(21, 16),
  157: datetime.time(21, 16, 1),
  158: datetime.time(21, 16, 3),
  159: datetime.time(21, 16, 6),
  160: datetime.time(21, 16, 7),
  161: datetime.time(21, 16, 10),
  162: datetime.time(21, 16, 12),
  163: datetime.time(21, 16, 16),
  164: datetime.time(21, 16, 18),
  165: datetime.time(21, 16, 21),
  166: datetime.time(21, 16, 28),
  167: datetime.time(21, 16, 31),
  168: datetime.time(21, 16, 33),
  169: datetime.time(21, 16, 41),
  170: datetime.time(21, 16, 43),
  171: datetime.time(21, 16, 46),
  172: datetime.time(21, 16, 54),
  173: datetime.time(21, 17, 1),
  174: datetime.time(21, 17, 7),
  175: datetime.time(21, 17, 13),
  176: datetime.time(21, 17, 19),
  177: datetime.time(21, 17, 28),
  178: datetime.time(21, 17, 35),
  179: datetime.time(21, 17, 42),
  180: datetime.time(21, 17, 51),
  181: datetime.time(21, 17, 53),
  182: datetime.time(21, 17, 57),
  183: datetime.time(21, 17, 59),
  184: datetime.time(21, 18, 2),
  185: datetime.time(21, 18, 10),
  186: datetime.time(21, 18, 19),
  187: datetime.time(21, 18, 29),
  188: datetime.time(21, 18, 37),
  189: datetime.time(21, 18, 43),
  190: datetime.time(21, 18, 44),
  191: datetime.time(21, 18, 51),
  192: datetime.time(21, 18, 53),
  193: datetime.time(21, 18, 55),
  194: datetime.time(21, 19),
  195: datetime.time(21, 19, 10),
  196: datetime.time(21, 19, 20),
  197: datetime.time(21, 19, 29),
  198: datetime.time(21, 19, 30),
  199: datetime.time(21, 19, 37),
  200: datetime.time(21, 19, 44),
  201: datetime.time(21, 19, 53),
  202: datetime.time(21, 19, 54),
  203: datetime.time(21, 20, 2),
  204: datetime.time(21, 20, 11),
  205: datetime.time(21, 20, 18),
  206: datetime.time(21, 20, 26),
  207: datetime.time(21, 20, 34),
  208: datetime.time(21, 20, 38),
  209: datetime.time(21, 20, 39),
  210: datetime.time(21, 20, 45),
  211: datetime.time(21, 20, 54),
  212: datetime.time(21, 21),
  213: datetime.time(21, 21, 5),
  214: datetime.time(21, 21, 7),
  215: datetime.time(21, 21, 12),
  216: datetime.time(21, 21, 15),
  217: datetime.time(21, 21, 24),
  218: datetime.time(21, 21, 28),
  219: datetime.time(21, 21, 32),
  220: datetime.time(21, 21, 41),
  221: datetime.time(21, 21, 50),
  222: datetime.time(21, 21, 59),
  223: datetime.time(21, 22, 1),
  224: datetime.time(21, 22, 9),
  225: datetime.time(21, 22, 17),
  226: datetime.time(21, 22, 18),
  227: datetime.time(21, 22, 22),
  228: datetime.time(21, 22, 23),
  229: datetime.time(21, 22, 27),
  230: datetime.time(21, 22, 29),
  231: datetime.time(21, 22, 37),
  232: datetime.time(21, 22, 38),
  233: datetime.time(21, 22, 44),
  234: datetime.time(21, 22, 53),
  235: datetime.time(21, 23, 1),
  236: datetime.time(21, 23, 2),
  237: datetime.time(21, 23, 7),
  238: datetime.time(21, 23, 16),
  239: datetime.time(21, 23, 23),
  240: datetime.time(21, 23, 27),
  241: datetime.time(21, 23, 29),
  242: datetime.time(21, 23, 36),
  243: datetime.time(21, 23, 44),
  244: datetime.time(21, 23, 50),
  245: datetime.time(21, 23, 55)},
 'Hour': {0: 21,
  1: 21,
  2: 21,
  3: 21,
  4: 21,
  5: 21,
  6: 21,
  7: 21,
  8: 21,
  9: 21,
  10: 21,
  11: 21,
  12: 21,
  13: 21,
  14: 21,
  15: 21,
  16: 21,
  17: 21,
  18: 21,
  19: 21,
  20: 21,
  21: 21,
  22: 21,
  23: 21,
  24: 21,
  25: 21,
  26: 21,
  27: 21,
  28: 21,
  29: 21,
  30: 21,
  31: 21,
  32: 21,
  33: 21,
  34: 21,
  35: 21,
  36: 21,
  37: 21,
  38: 21,
  39: 21,
  40: 21,
  41: 21,
  42: 21,
  43: 21,
  44: 21,
  45: 21,
  46: 21,
  47: 21,
  48: 21,
  49: 21,
  50: 21,
  51: 21,
  52: 21,
  53: 21,
  54: 21,
  55: 21,
  56: 21,
  57: 21,
  58: 21,
  59: 21,
  60: 21,
  61: 21,
  62: 21,
  63: 21,
  64: 21,
  65: 21,
  66: 21,
  67: 21,
  68: 21,
  69: 21,
  70: 21,
  71: 21,
  72: 21,
  73: 21,
  74: 21,
  75: 21,
  76: 21,
  77: 21,
  78: 21,
  79: 21,
  80: 21,
  81: 21,
  82: 21,
  83: 21,
  84: 21,
  85: 21,
  86: 21,
  87: 21,
  88: 21,
  89: 21,
  90: 21,
  91: 21,
  92: 21,
  93: 21,
  94: 21,
  95: 21,
  96: 21,
  97: 21,
  98: 21,
  99: 21,
  100: 21,
  101: 21,
  102: 21,
  103: 21,
  104: 21,
  105: 21,
  106: 21,
  107: 21,
  108: 21,
  109: 21,
  110: 21,
  111: 21,
  112: 21,
  113: 21,
  114: 21,
  115: 21,
  116: 21,
  117: 21,
  118: 21,
  119: 21,
  120: 21,
  121: 21,
  122: 21,
  123: 21,
  124: 21,
  125: 21,
  126: 21,
  127: 21,
  128: 21,
  129: 21,
  130: 21,
  131: 21,
  132: 21,
  133: 21,
  134: 21,
  135: 21,
  136: 21,
  137: 21,
  138: 21,
  139: 21,
  140: 21,
  141: 21,
  142: 21,
  143: 21,
  144: 21,
  145: 21,
  146: 21,
  147: 21,
  148: 21,
  149: 21,
  150: 21,
  151: 21,
  152: 21,
  153: 21,
  154: 21,
  155: 21,
  156: 21,
  157: 21,
  158: 21,
  159: 21,
  160: 21,
  161: 21,
  162: 21,
  163: 21,
  164: 21,
  165: 21,
  166: 21,
  167: 21,
  168: 21,
  169: 21,
  170: 21,
  171: 21,
  172: 21,
  173: 21,
  174: 21,
  175: 21,
  176: 21,
  177: 21,
  178: 21,
  179: 21,
  180: 21,
  181: 21,
  182: 21,
  183: 21,
  184: 21,
  185: 21,
  186: 21,
  187: 21,
  188: 21,
  189: 21,
  190: 21,
  191: 21,
  192: 21,
  193: 21,
  194: 21,
  195: 21,
  196: 21,
  197: 21,
  198: 21,
  199: 21,
  200: 21,
  201: 21,
  202: 21,
  203: 21,
  204: 21,
  205: 21,
  206: 21,
  207: 21,
  208: 21,
  209: 21,
  210: 21,
  211: 21,
  212: 21,
  213: 21,
  214: 21,
  215: 21,
  216: 21,
  217: 21,
  218: 21,
  219: 21,
  220: 21,
  221: 21,
  222: 21,
  223: 21,
  224: 21,
  225: 21,
  226: 21,
  227: 21,
  228: 21,
  229: 21,
  230: 21,
  231: 21,
  232: 21,
  233: 21,
  234: 21,
  235: 21,
  236: 21,
  237: 21,
  238: 21,
  239: 21,
  240: 21,
  241: 21,
  242: 21,
  243: 21,
  244: 21,
  245: 21},
 'Minute': {0: 4,
  1: 4,
  2: 4,
  3: 4,
  4: 4,
  5: 4,
  6: 4,
  7: 4,
  8: 4,
  9: 4,
  10: 4,
  11: 4,
  12: 4,
  13: 4,
  14: 4,
  15: 4,
  16: 4,
  17: 4,
  18: 4,
  19: 4,
  20: 4,
  21: 4,
  22: 4,
  23: 4,
  24: 5,
  25: 5,
  26: 5,
  27: 5,
  28: 5,
  29: 5,
  30: 5,
  31: 5,
  32: 5,
  33: 5,
  34: 5,
  35: 5,
  36: 5,
  37: 6,
  38: 6,
  39: 6,
  40: 6,
  41: 6,
  42: 6,
  43: 6,
  44: 6,
  45: 6,
  46: 6,
  47: 7,
  48: 7,
  49: 7,
  50: 7,
  51: 7,
  52: 7,
  53: 7,
  54: 7,
  55: 7,
  56: 7,
  57: 7,
  58: 8,
  59: 8,
  60: 8,
  61: 8,
  62: 8,
  63: 8,
  64: 8,
  65: 8,
  66: 8,
  67: 8,
  68: 8,
  69: 9,
  70: 9,
  71: 9,
  72: 9,
  73: 9,
  74: 9,
  75: 9,
  76: 9,
  77: 9,
  78: 9,
  79: 9,
  80: 10,
  81: 10,
  82: 10,
  83: 10,
  84: 10,
  85: 10,
  86: 10,
  87: 10,
  88: 10,
  89: 10,
  90: 10,
  91: 10,
  92: 10,
  93: 10,
  94: 11,
  95: 11,
  96: 11,
  97: 11,
  98: 11,
  99: 11,
  100: 11,
  101: 11,
  102: 11,
  103: 11,
  104: 11,
  105: 11,
  106: 11,
  107: 12,
  108: 12,
  109: 12,
  110: 12,
  111: 12,
  112: 12,
  113: 12,
  114: 12,
  115: 12,
  116: 12,
  117: 12,
  118: 12,
  119: 12,
  120: 12,
  121: 12,
  122: 12,
  123: 12,
  124: 13,
  125: 13,
  126: 13,
  127: 13,
  128: 13,
  129: 13,
  130: 13,
  131: 13,
  132: 13,
  133: 13,
  134: 13,
  135: 14,
  136: 14,
  137: 14,
  138: 14,
  139: 14,
  140: 14,
  141: 14,
  142: 14,
  143: 14,
  144: 14,
  145: 15,
  146: 15,
  147: 15,
  148: 15,
  149: 15,
  150: 15,
  151: 15,
  152: 15,
  153: 15,
  154: 15,
  155: 15,
  156: 16,
  157: 16,
  158: 16,
  159: 16,
  160: 16,
  161: 16,
  162: 16,
  163: 16,
  164: 16,
  165: 16,
  166: 16,
  167: 16,
  168: 16,
  169: 16,
  170: 16,
  171: 16,
  172: 16,
  173: 17,
  174: 17,
  175: 17,
  176: 17,
  177: 17,
  178: 17,
  179: 17,
  180: 17,
  181: 17,
  182: 17,
  183: 17,
  184: 18,
  185: 18,
  186: 18,
  187: 18,
  188: 18,
  189: 18,
  190: 18,
  191: 18,
  192: 18,
  193: 18,
  194: 19,
  195: 19,
  196: 19,
  197: 19,
  198: 19,
  199: 19,
  200: 19,
  201: 19,
  202: 19,
  203: 20,
  204: 20,
  205: 20,
  206: 20,
  207: 20,
  208: 20,
  209: 20,
  210: 20,
  211: 20,
  212: 21,
  213: 21,
  214: 21,
  215: 21,
  216: 21,
  217: 21,
  218: 21,
  219: 21,
  220: 21,
  221: 21,
  222: 21,
  223: 22,
  224: 22,
  225: 22,
  226: 22,
  227: 22,
  228: 22,
  229: 22,
  230: 22,
  231: 22,
  232: 22,
  233: 22,
  234: 22,
  235: 23,
  236: 23,
  237: 23,
  238: 23,
  239: 23,
  240: 23,
  241: 23,
  242: 23,
  243: 23,
  244: 23,
  245: 23}}
```

How did it right shifted?

Comment: Seaborn draws the boxplot and swarmplot with a categorical x-axis, so placed at positions 0,1,2,... while the lineplot uses a numeric x-axis. One approach is to convert the numerical `'minute'` column to strings, to also make the lineplot categorical.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JohanC 's comment:

> Seaborn draws the boxplot and swarmplot with a categorical x-axis, so
> placed at positions 0,1,2,... while the lineplot uses a numeric
> x-axis. One approach is to convert the numerical 'minute' column to
> strings, to also make the lineplot categorical.

It turns out that making the 'Minute' column to string type has solve this problem.